# Using Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem for the Van der Pol oscillator

Tags: dynamical-systems

**Statement**: Use the Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem to show that the Van der Pol oscillator
$$ \ddot{x}+\varepsilon(x^2-1)\dot{x}+x = 0,\; \; \varepsilon >0 $$
has at least one stable limit cycle for sufficiently small values of $\varepsilon$.

**Approach:** First, I rewrite the equation as a 2D system:
$$\begin{aligned}
\dot{x}=&y\\ 
\dot{y}=&-x-\varepsilon (x^2-1)y
\end{aligned}
$$
We observe that $(0,0)$ is the unique fixed point.

Doing a change of variables to polar coordinates, $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,\: r \sin\theta)$, the system has the following expression:
$$\begin{aligned}
\dot{r}=&-\varepsilon r \sin^2\theta(r^2\cos^2\theta-1)\\ 
\dot{\theta}=&-1-\varepsilon (r^2\cos^2\theta-1)\sin\theta \cos\theta
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, I need to find a positively invariant compact set with no fixed point (so I can apply Poincaré-Bendixson theorem and state it exists a periodic orbit). To avoid the fixed point (0,0), I consider a small circle of radius $r^-<1$. In the boundary of the circle, $\dot{r}>0$, so the flux goes in outside direction. But now I don't know how to close the set to do it positively invariant. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a very complicated task. While you can easily find inner circles or ellipses with flows to the outside, away from the origin ([Stability of Van der Pol oscillator](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2959021/115115)), to find such a curve from the outside seems impossible. Use $εv=\dot x + ε(\frac{x^3}3-x)$ as second phase variable to get close to the analysis of a fast-slow flow system (Lienard system). Using polar coordinates and averaging results in another classical approach for small $ε$ ([Averaging of the Van der Pol equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3147771/115115))

Comment: The approach of Lyapunov functions for Liénard systems([Stability in a Liénard system](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2480866/115115) and [Setting Lineard Equation ODE into standard form](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1651435/115115)) is close, but not really applicable, as the friction coefficient $ε(x^2−1)$ is negative for $|x|<1$, so that outside the limit cycle segments of acceleration and deceleration alternate.